# CodeIgniter ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

My website was running ok when I made an update to a stable version of code and database. These updates are a regular thing, and we do it once in a week to fix small bugs and so on.

The point is that after I ran the migrations, the site started to show ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error. Sad thing is that this version of the code is running ok in all development enviroments, same to other production enviroment. Phpinfo() works fine, and IF I change the enviroment to something wrong (i.e. productyonn), CodeIgniter shows me the enviroment is set wrong.

I tried to reverse the commits to version before the update, but the error persists. Did the same to the database.

Here is my `.htaccess` file, on `application/cache`

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

It is hard to say more things, because I honestly have no ideia about what is going on the server. **SysAdmin is not open to an Apache restart,** too many systems running on the same apache, he said.

Comment: Because you reverted and the problems persists then I would be inclined to think the problem isn't with your code. If there is additional info in the error message window please share it. As I understand it this error is associated with the client side and not the server. It could be the browser, network infrastructure (i.e. routers, firewalls) or possibly a workstation update that hosed your networking. Most often sited cure I've found is to do a hard refresh of the page and/or flush the browser's cache.

Comment: Please don't use the Code Snippets feature for code that cannot possibly run within this window.  It's only meant for HTML/JavaScript/CSS and you should have seen that, as each pane is clearly labeled as such.  Edited.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry for the bad post.

Unfortunaly there is not any message, not even on apache log. I dont think it is just a client problem because I can't reach the site anywhere.